# Can I close a browser activity I've opened?

Tags: android, android-activity

My app opens a browser activity via startActivity(). Can I close that browser activity if I feel like it?

For one thing, startActivity() does not return anything - can I get an Activity object back from it somehow?

In the JavaScript world, the convention is that whoever opened a new browser window has the authority to close it. Just sayin'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217942/android-intent-flag-activity-single-top-and-intent-flag-activity-clear-top), if you activate the root activity with the following intent flags:

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
```

it will finish all activities on top of it in the navigation stack. Including the browser.

Answer (score 4):

I think you getting hopefully answer from this post

[Starting an ACTION_VIEW activity to open the browser, how do I return to my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248870/starting-an-action-view-activity-to-open-the-browser-how-do-i-return-to-my-app)

[Clear back stack after activity is opened from web-browser by url "appname://com.appname/"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183423/clear-back-stack-after-activity-is-opened-from-web-browser-by-url-appname-com)

Answer (score 3):

No you can't. You don't have control over browser activity. You can use [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) to embed the browser in custom activity on which you'll have full control and call [finish()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29) when you want.

Comment: +1 I'll think of it... does not quite fit my scenario, since I don't want to replicate Refresh, Go, Back/Forward and the rest of the browser framing.

Answer (score 1):

**No** you can not get a handle for the Activity object.

---

**VERY DANGEROUS**

Try using a `Handler` or any other way to send a backspace key which usually closes the activity. Will it work?

However keep in mind that this is **completely wrong**