# Launch browser from within app - how do you get back to the app?

Tags: android, browser, android-activity, android-intent

I've got the following to open up a browser from within an Android app.

```
String url = "http://www.example.com";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

How do you get the user back to the app after they have viewed the page?

*Edit*

I have `android:noHistory="true"` set in my manifest for the `Activity` calling the `Intent`.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927112/can-i-close-a-browser-activity-ive-opened/6927196#6927196

Comment: I agree with Graeme and create your own webview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the calling Activity is in the `Backstack` (as default) the user would press "back" to peal the top layer off the stack.

However if the browser closes, the Activity does too, and the last Activity in the `Backstack` comes to the fore. If you own the site your going to and can put a "back" button in it (With javascript `window.close()` or similar), the activity will close and your applications topmost activity in the stack will resume.

If your Activity ***isn't*** in the backstack then I would suggest instead of sending the user to the browser `Task` use a custom `Activity` containing a `WebView` giving you full control (such as manually starting the original Activity through an Intent)

Answer (score 1):

You can't. They have to press the back button to get back to your app.